# Node File Line Count

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I got feedback that this node function has performance issues in obtaining the line count of a file but haven't been able to pinpoint the exact details.

```
function countFileLines(filePath){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let lineCount = 0;
  fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    .on("data", (buffer) => {
      buffer.forEach((chunk) => {
        if (chunk === 10) lineCount++;
      });
    }).on("end", () => {
      resolve(lineCount);
    }).on("error", reject);
  });
};
```

Is there a more performant way in obtaining the line count of a file in Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speculate but `buffer.forEach` calling a function and doing a comparison for every byte could be the problem. Consider using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to let the VM find the newlines for you:

```
function countFileLines(filePath){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let lineCount = 0;
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .on("data", (buffer) => {
        let idx = -1;
        lineCount--; // Because the loop will run once for idx=-1
        do {
          idx = buffer.indexOf(10, idx+1);
          lineCount++;
        } while (idx !== -1);
      }).on("end", () => {
        resolve(lineCount);
      }).on("error", reject);
    });
};
```

What this solution does is that it finds the position of the first newline using `.indexOf`. It increments `lineCount`, then it finds the next position. The second parameter to `.indexOf` tells where to start looking for newlines. This way we are jumping over large chunks of the buffer. The while loop will run once for every newline, plus one.

We are letting the Node runtime do the searching for us which is implemented on a lower level and should be faster.

On my system this is about twice as fast as running a `for` loop over the buffer length on a large file (111 MB).

Comment: Does it perform more efficiently than if I were to use a regular for loop?

Comment: Yes. I tried running this three times with my function, and three times with Qiaosen's answer on the same machine with the same file. The fastest time for my function was 443 ms. The fastest with their was 812 ms.

Comment: Damn, I compared both answers with 2 large directories; both versions are a significant boost, but yours is faster. 

The logic isn't intuitive, but it's brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
function countFileLines(filePath){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let lineCount = 0;
  let i = 0;
  fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    .on("data", (buffer) => {
      for (i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
        if (buffer[i] == 10) lineCount++;
      }
    }).on("end", () => {
      resolve(lineCount);
    }).on("error", reject);
  });
};
```

for comparison:

original: `node index.js  2.38s user 0.29s system 98% cpu 2.713 total`

modifed: `node index2.js  0.18s user 0.04s system 96% cpu 0.225 total`

Comment: Can you explain why you increment `lineCount` when `buffer[I] === 10`? Thanks!

Comment: @philosopher String.fromCharCode(10) == '\n'